# how to find HKMetadataKeyMaximumSpeed

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how to find a user's top speed using `HealthKit`.

I have come across this [`HKMetadataKeyMaximumSpeed`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeymaximumspeed) but have no idea how to implement/use it. The docs are not very clear to me.

Can anyone provide any help here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is example provided by Apple in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkoutactivitytype/hkworkoutactivitytypesnowboarding/receiving_downhill_skiing_and_snowboarding_data).

```
func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didGenerate event: HKWorkoutEvent) {
    
    // Check to see if the event is a segment.
    if event.type == .segment {
        
        // Get the segment's start and end times.
        let startTime = event.dateInterval.start
        let endTime = event.dateInterval.end
        
        // Get the segment's metadata.
        let averageSpeed = event.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyAverageSpeed]
        let maxSpeed = event.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyMaximumSpeed]
        let alpineSlope = event.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyAlpineSlopeGrade]
        let elevationAscended = event.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyElevationAscended]
        let elevationDescended = event.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyElevationDescended]
        
        // Do something with the segment data here...
        
    }
    
    // Also handle any other event types...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I saw that, do you know if it needs to be Downhill Skiing and Snowboarding Data?

Comment: also, any idea how to generate these events on the simulator?

Comment: From docs [HKMetadataKeyMaximumSpeed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeymaximumspeed) it looks like its added only for that 2. ```HealthKit assigns this metadata key to the segments it automatically creates for HKWorkoutActivityType.downhillSkiing and HKWorkoutActivityType.snowboarding workout sessions (Apple Watch Series 3 only)```

Comment: It looks like it's not working on [simulator](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/49390?answerId=146114022#146114022).

Comment: @peterflanagan if my answer was helpful, please accept the answer or vote up

Answer (score 3):

Apple indicates thath :

> **HKMetadataKeyMaximumSpeed** Set this key on a workout, workout segment, or a quantity sample that represents distance. Set its value to an HKQuantity object with a length/time unit (for example, m/s)

So you can use this function with this property :

```
func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didGenerate event: HKWorkoutEvent) {

if event.type == .segment {
    
    let maxSpeed = event.metadata?[HKMetadataKeyMaximumSpeed]

    // do it here your logic     
}
```

Regarding to your comment: You can not genererate these events on the simulator.

Comment: so I literally need to go snowboarding to test this? :-D

Comment: haha yeah also you should need to wait for enough snow :D

Comment: gave you a vote.. the other guy got there first to be fair

Comment: it is ok, next time :)